# TabLayout not visible when using with AppBarLayout?

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-appbarlayout

In my application I am using Navigation Drawer,my **main activity layout** is like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_main.xml is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"></FrameLayout>

    <!--  <include layout="@layout/content_main" /> -->

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**tab_fragment.xml is:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0.0dip"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white" />


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Everything works fine and tab fragment loads successfully with data but tabs doesn't shows up. Its seems tabs are hidden behind the toolbar/appBarLayout.Could someone please help me how can I re-arrange my code to show the tabs?

Comment: Your `TabLayout` Must be included inside `AppBarLayout` right after `Toolbar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following attribute in your `FrameLayout`

`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`